Has Trump changed his political views on Israel's war in Gaza?
Trump is a strong supporter of US ally Israel. On April 14, 2024, Washington Post reported - Trump supporters echo pro-Palestinian ‘genocide Joe’ chant:

“Genocide Joe” is a phrase used by pro-Palestine protesters against President Biden because of his unconditional support of Israel amid its onslaught in Gaza. But supporters of former president Donald Trump adopted the chant at his campaign rally Saturday night ... Supporters began to chant “genocide Joe, genocide Joe,” as Trump spoke from a stage in a large field at the Schnecksville fire hall.
Trump paused before saying: “They’re not wrong, they’re not wrong. He’s done everything wrong.”
... Congressional Republicans have urged more U.S. support for Israel, although the Republican-controlled House has yet to take up a bill passed months ago in the Democratic-controlled Senate that would send aid to Israel along with Ukraine and the Indo-Pacific.

This is obviously a clever political campaign to sway some of the anti-war protestors to not vote for Biden, without making any real political commitments to them.
The term "Genocide Joe" is obviously meant to disparage Biden which Trump supporters may find appealing. But the term "genocide" in it also brings attention to the gross human rights violation of Palestinians in Gaza and also invokes sympathy for them amongst the Republicans. This must obviously be making some American supporters of Israel and the Israeli administration very uncomfortable. So it could also indicate a shift in Trump's political views on Israel's war in Gaza as a growing majority in U.S. now disapprove of Israeli action in Gaza.
Are there any supporting evidence to suggest that Trump's political views on the ongoing Israel war have changed?

Also, he's recently claimed to have visited Gaza, although nobody seem to know when https://edition.cnn.com/2024/10/08/politics/trump-gaza-fact-check/index.html

Yes and no. Trump has not taken a strong stance on the issue of the war in Gaza, so there's not much to compare previous stances to. That said, what little he has said does seem to suggest at least a small shift.
Trump's video on Oct 13 could be summed up as

I kept Israel safe

That isn't a position as much as a campaign slogan. Trump's first quote on the war appears to have been on March 5

“You’ve got to finish the problem,” Trump said on Fox News on Tuesday when asked about the war. “You had a horrible invasion that took place that would have never happened if I was president.”

And later

“President Trump did more for Israel than any American President in history, and he took historic action in the Middle East that created unprecedented peace,” Karoline Leavitt, Trump’s national press secretary, said in a statement, adding, "When President Trump is back in the Oval Office, Israel will once again be protected, Iran will go back to being broke, terrorists will be hunted down, and the bloodshed will end.”

Israel Hayom did an interview with Trump on Mar 25. He was asked about the rise in antisemitism and this was Trump's response

Well, that's because you fought back. And I think Israel made a very big mistake. I wanted to call [Israel] and say don't do it. These photos and shots. I mean, moving shots of bombs being dropped into buildings in Gaza. And I said, Oh, that's a terrible portrait. It's a very bad picture for the world. The world is seeing this…every night, I would watch buildings pour down on people. It would say it was given by  the Defense Ministry, and said whoever's providing that that's a bad image.

That looks like a shift from "finish it". Then, there's this exchange on Apr 4

HEWITT: But you are still standing 100% with Israel? You achieved the
Abraham Accords, which was the first peace deal since Sadat.
TRUMP: Right.
HEWITT: And so are you still 100% with Israel? And what’s your advice to
Netanyahu beyond get it over with in a hurry?
TRUMP: Well, that’s all the advice you can give. I mean, that’s the
advice. You’ve got to get it over with, and you have to get back to
normalcy. And I’m not sure that I’m loving the way they’re doing it,
because you’ve got to have victory. You have to have a victory, and
it’s taking a long time. And the other thing is I hate, they put out
tapes all the time. Every night, they’re releasing tapes of a building
falling down. They shouldn’t be releasing tapes like that. They’re
doing, that’s why they’re losing the PR war. They, Israel is
absolutely losing the PR war.

This seems contradictory on the surface. Standing with Israel "100%" is hard to square with "Israel is absolutely losing the PR war."
The position here seems to be "Get the war over with so it's no longer a political issue." It's unclear what Trump's position will be if the war continues to drag on. He clearly doesn't like the optics, but that's not terribly dissimilar to the views of Joe Biden.
As to the "Genocide Joe" chanting, Trump loves chants denouncing his political rivals. His 2016 rallies featured crowds chanting "Lock her up" in relation to Hillary Clinton, the 2016 Democratic nominee. Since Clinton was not ever charged by Trump's DOJ, it's hard to believe this represents a policy position.

Standing with Israel "100%" is hard to square with "Israel is absolutely losing the PR war." - this might just be the fact that "standing with" is not a well defined term.

There's this too - Trump courts Arab and Muslim support, with Harris criticized for ‘not engaging’. And as another answer points out, he explicitly promised Arab-Americans that he would "bring peace" in the middle-east. (I honestly don't think this will happen but it is telling that he specifically reached out and campaigned to American muslim voters despite them traditionally voting Democrat).

Also - In scene unimaginable 4 years ago, Michigan’s Arab Americans bask in aiding Trump win : "But Bahbah insisted that “the Trump of 2016 and 2020 is a very different person than the Trump of 2024" ... He’s been exposed to the Arab Muslim American communities. He has had at least 15 meetings with Arab and Muslim leaders ... Indeed, a new member of Trump’s inner circle is Lebanese-born businessman Massad Boulos, whose son Michael married Tiffany Trump in 2022 ... “During his administration, there were no new wars, and he worked to pull the US out of wars ..."


Are there any supporting evidence to suggest that Trump's political views on the ongoing Israel war has changed?

Trump doesn't take positions.
First, Trump doesn't have any real power now. So we're going on rhetoric and past actions. That said, Trump doesn't have many policy and moral positions. He says what he thinks people want to hear with a bias towards what his supporters want to hear. He is a populist mirror. His number one monetary interest is his brand. When his brand would not suffer he relies on other material interests to change his mind.
That is to say nothing changed.
And as pointed out in this coverage by the news outlet Breaking Points on Trump's agreement with the term "Genocide Joe", this is the strongest argument for supporting Trump to bring an end to the conflict:

Biden is an ideological Zionist, and always was.
Trump is likely to do what's in his best interest at that time; and, as you've shown in the question, it's not in Biden's best interest to continue down a massively unpopular path of supporting Israel and ultimately suffering an electoral defeat for a bloc that will almost certainly support the Republicans anyway.

Trump in Biden's position would flail and then realign (likely stirring up drama and firing everyone in the process).

I think your characterization of Trump is fair; what could be added is that his not having strong convictions makes him an ideal vehicle for people who do (advisers, donors, lobby groups etc.) in synergy with his populism. That is evident in his anti-abortion and general conservative-Christian agenda which, by inference from his relationships and conduct, is probably not his original stance.

It is indirectly relevant. I used it as an example where it is very clear that he has strongly claimed positions that do not originate in his personal convictions. This supports the idea that his Israel/Arab positions are similarly not his own convictions (and hence potentially subject to change), even if there is less evidence from his pre-political life. (There is evidence for his stance on cultural issues because like everybody he was embedded in and interacting with culture; but Trump did not interact much with politics in his earlier life, so there is not that much evidence.)

I don't think it's convincing argument, nor a persuasive one. You've listed "advisers, donors, lobby groups", I don't see Trump as being more influenced by these groups than others. I agree, he doesn't have principles that sit higher on the totem then the things you've listed; you can't reason because principals aren't higher he'll be more influenced by money. He could have a different number of things higher than money, with the same or greater weight. And he could have more things on his totem north of money too -- he simply needs less of it. He doesn't have to outspend Biden to win.

I would argue that changing your rhetoric based on what you think your supporters want is in fact a change in position. It doesn't matter if he actually holds those positions himself: the change is what position he is publicly supporting.

@trlkly May be. Is there a Turing test for politicians? Is there an ontological difference between the positions a politician projects to the public and the ones they have? ;-)

"Free Gaza, Vote for Trump" eh?

@ItalianPhilosopher who said vote for Trump? What are you even talking about? I certainly would never suggest anyone vote Trump. On this one issue, I don't believe Trump would be as bad. But there is no outcome with Trump or Harris that's good for Palestine. https://x.com/TheEvanCarroll/status/1850622665792623013/photo/1

@EvanCarroll Oh, my bad.  It was someone else who was asking about their "Abandon Harris Free Palestine" T-shirt.

@ItalianPhilosopher If you read "Abandon Harris" to be "vote for Trump" perhaps you should go ask ChatGPT or the like "Who else is running in the general election for US president 2024, and why would I want to vote for them". And because you're a "philosopher" perhaps add this to your reading list.

@EvanCarroll Oh, I heartily dislike philosophy as a subject.  However, the US is not round 1 of a French presidential election - a protest vote is a lot more consequential.  Anyways, not just me making this claim about Trump being extra pro-Israel, the Israeli themselves do  I realize that people are frustrated with how badly the Palestinians are treated over time.  And people are free to vote for Trump - or not vote for Harris - for their own reasons, but saying that helps Palestinians is an illusion.

I didn't say Trump wasn't pro-Israel: he is. Though as indicated in my answer here, I make no other assumption then he goes where the money goes. My problem here is either you knew I wasn't pro-Trump and you're trolling (in which case, weak), or you thought wrongly that I was pro-Trump and I want to clarify. There is no doubt voting is consequential in the aggregate, protest or not. And I voted.

That you and I both think it's unlikely Jill Stein will win obviously weighs differently for the both of us. I value the consequential message that genocide is a red line and unacceptable, more than I value the consequential difference between pro-Israel Harris and pro-Israel Trump. A majority of the Democratic base now sympathizes with Palestine and stands against unconditioned arms to Israel. I send the message that to win, the party must not deviate from the base on this and into genocide. If they lose, that's fine. I value the message and future anti-Genocide reform more than winning.

Also, side note, the other false dichotomy (not just d-vs-r) here is protest-vs-politics. These things are not separate. You don't get a Civil Rights Act (obviously political and directly influencing power) without sending a message to power brokers and threatening power with things like March on Washington (which show an organization one can't neglect). Whether 300,000 people on the foot of the capital, or enough Democrats protesting so the DNC can never win another election this is always the process. It's the refusal to play ball that gets the goods.

Jill Stein seems to be a joke.  The problem is that getting Trump is likely to be a lot more directly hurtful to the Palestinians than Harris would be, so whatever your motivations they don't seem to achieve zilch wrt to the people you want to help.  If that makes you principled and me cynical, so be it ;-)  Btw, your profile's BDS thingyis rather dated:  while S. African style sanctions may indeed be necessary to force Israel to a 2 state solution, BDS released a "Good job, Hamas!" on 10/8 so they'll never lead it.

That article is a joke. To talk about "Stein’s ethical compromises" is insane in the context of the Green Party having a holding in a mutual fund, when they're running against establishment politicians that are taking money from AIPAC while giving money to Israel to fund genocide. A new benchmark for shilling.

@ItalianPhilosopher I know you're trying hard to provide an intellectual critique, but _"vote for and empower the people genociding you because otherwise you won't achieve 'zilch'" is a bizarre political stance.

Highly unlikely.

Supporters began to chant “genocide Joe, genocide Joe,” as Trump spoke from a stage in a large field at the Schnecksville fire hall.


Trump paused before saying: “They’re not wrong, they’re not wrong. He’s done everything wrong.”

Sooo...?  "Genocide Joe" joins "Sleepy Joe" joins "Crooked Joe" in Trump's menagerie of name calling.  Are we now going to gauge his policy goals by his choice of epithets?  LOL.
Something more concrete perhaps?
Let's look at the May attempt, after this question was asked, by the Biden administration to hold back 2000 pound bombs because of the belief that no good can come of using them in a heavily populated urban area like Gaza.
Biden May 9

President Joe Biden said for the first time Wednesday he would halt some shipments of American weapons to Israel – which he acknowledged have been used to kill civilians in Gaza – if Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu orders a major invasion of the city of Rafah.


“Civilians have been killed in Gaza as a consequence of those bombs and other ways in which they go after population centers,” Biden told CNN’s Erin Burnett in an exclusive interview on “Erin Burnett OutFront,” referring to 2,000-pound bombs that Biden paused shipments of last week.

Politifact 

President Joe Biden’s administration paused one shipment of 3,500 bombs to Israel hoping to prevent a full-scale attack on Gaza — a move that former President Donald Trump condemned.

Trump himself, May 10
(do notice the timeline, within 24 hrs of Biden's statement)

Biden wants to immediately stop all aid to Israel. Any Jewish person who votes for Crooked Joe Biden should have his/her head examined!

And an act to unblock the withholding of those bombs was duly tabled by the Republicans through the Israel Security Assistance Support Act (H.R. 8369).
As of June 27th, the 500#ers were back and the 2000#ers were still on hold.
Criticism of an incumbent's crisis handling is standard, standard, fare.
Seriously, criticizing an incumbent's handling of a crisis is an effective strategy, wielded by many politicians.  In many cases, even seasoned and competent politicians will take the opportunity to do so without giving details of what their own policy would have been instead.  It's the proverbial "low hanging fruit".  They don't have to!  All gain, no pain.
On a subject as complicated and controversial as Israel-Palestine, most politicians would be careful about taking a strong position on exactly what they would have done.
Following that trend of being very vague certainly hasn't stopped Trump from his usual bombast:

“If I were president, that war would have never started. We wouldn’t have had October 7,” Trump told Al Arabiya, regarding the massacre in which Hamas terrorists killed approximately 1,200 people and took 250 hostages.

Now, he's gone out and managed to sell the idea that he's the "candidate for peace".
Like ending the Ukraine war, which also would have never happened, in 24 hours...  Or getting Mexico to pay for the wall.
i.e. There is ample precedent for Trump making big claims.  In this case, he seems to be telling Bibi one thing, Muslim voters another.

According to Senator Lindsey Graham (note:  a longtime Trump ally), Trump was especially impressed by Israel expanding its war to Lebanon, and told Netanyahu as much.

It would be a very odd reversal
Support for Israel, come what may (and 10/7 was a traumatic, terrorist, event) is pretty much a constant for US administrations.  Occasionally, a POTUS will clash on Israel's stance, like Bush Sr at the end of his second term, but that is very much an exception.
One can applaud, or criticize, unconditional US support for Israel, but it is the reality in US foreign policy.  Biden, or any of his predecessors in the last 50 years, would have been very unlikely to stop Israel from responding to the atrocities of 10/7.
However, during his administration, Trump went beyond that, with the recognition of the annexation of the Golan and moving the embassy to Jerusalem.  These moves weren't required by any particular context at the time, unlike Biden's support since 10/7.  Nor did he really get anything in return, such as a freeze on settlements.  There was also the much-hyped Middle East "Plan for Peace" under Kuchner's watch which was anything but even-handed.

Robert Malley, director of the International Crisis Group and a leading Middle East expert in former U.S. administrations, stated: "Strip away the domestic and Israeli political considerations that determined the timing of the plan's release, and the message to the Palestinians, boiled down to its essence, is: You've lost, get over it."

This was widely reported at the time and surprised very few people.
Last, but not least, the Evangelicals are a massive, massive, part of Trump's support base, voting at 75-80% for him in the last 2 elections.  And, guess what, they are very, very, supportive of Israel.
Pew Research, 2022

Religious affiliation also matters: White evangelical Protestants are much more likely than members of any other major Christian tradition to say the best outcome would be a single state with an Israeli government; 28% say this, compared with 6% each of Catholics, White non-evangelical Protestants and Black Protestants.


Perhaps relatedly, White evangelicals also are the group most likely to say God gave the land that is now Israel to the Jewish people. Fully 70% of White evangelicals take that position, more than twice the share of U.S. Jews who answered a similar (but not identical) question in a 2020 survey by saying God gave the land of Israel to the Jewish people (32%).

USA Today June, 2024 - Survey: Christians favor Israel over Palestinians in Israel-Hamas war says more or less the same thing.

"the withholding of those bombs was duly blocked by the Republicans through Israel Security Assistance Support Act (H.R. 8369)." -- It seems it wasn't actually blocked. The HR in Q didn't seem to make it past the Senate https://www.congress.gov/bill/118th-congress/house-bill/8369/all-actions But surely was a shot across the bow.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Ah, wasn't sure.  Did the bomb shipments resume though?  I am pretty sure something was passed, or maybe I am confusing with an attempt to pass something.

Well, it's hard to be sure what was sent in the first place and when https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57421/did-the-us-send-14-000-mk84-2000lbs-bombs-to-israel-between-oct-2023-and-june-20

I think the main view of Trump is that Biden handled everything badly. Besides that you'd have to read his ultimate position/strategy between the lines.
E.g. he's tried to intimidate Hamas to release the hostages before he assumes office.

“I will give Israel the support that it needs to win but I do want them to win fast,” Trump added.
At the same event, Trump warned Hamas and other “enemies around the world: We want our hostages back and they better be back before I assume office.”

But at the same time (in April) he wrote that there are far fewer hostages alive than commonly believed.

Trump wrote that Israel and Hamas are unable to negotiate a deal to release hostages because “there are far fewer hostages than currently being thought,” adding “Hamas is incapable of holding Jewish people for a long period of time without killing them.”

Was he encouraging Israel to declare the same? As way to end the war? Who knows?!
Trump has also opposed a ceasefire (in August).

“From the start, Harris has worked to tie Israel’s hand behind its back, demanding an immediate ceasefire, always demanding ceasefire,” Trump said at his August press conference. A ceasefire “would only give Hamas time to regroup and launch a new October 7-style attack.”

Anyhow, this is only somewhat related to the war in Gaza proper, but unlike Biden, Trump said that Israel should bomb Iran's nuclear facilities "first".

And if that messaging isn't contradictory enough (to the OP's), today:

“We are building the biggest and broadest coalition in American political history. This includes record-breaking numbers of Arab and Muslim Voters in Michigan who want PEACE,” Trump writes on X.
“They know Kamala and her warmonger Cabinet will invade the Middle East, get millions of Muslims killed and start World War III,” he [Trump] adds, pledging to “BRING BACK PEACE!”

Basically Trump applies the Russian [dis]information campaign playbook: say whatever may sway someone, even if the messaging to different audiences is rather contradictory.
